# how to know which dll is missing into qtcreator

Tags: dll, qt-creator

I am currently using QtCreator for a Qt project on Windows. That application needs multiple libraries.

If one dll is miss, QtCreator only write :

> "your_application" crashed.

When I launch the application from Windows Explorer (after copying Qt's dll), I get the following message in a pop-up window :

> The program can't start because "missing_dll" is missing. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I was wondering if having this message **into QtCreator** was possible?